# Dynamic Picturebox creation into just showed MdiChildForm

Tags: c#, forms, show, picturebox, mdichild

hope some of you can help me.
I have one PictureBox Array to show into an MdiChildForm just after it's showed.
But when I run the program, in the "CreatePictureBox" Method, which I execute only after I show the form I get a NullReferenceException. Why?

Here's the code of FormShowing

```
    private void packOpeningToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProvaPackOpening ProvaPackOpening = new ProvaPackOpening();
        ProvaPackOpening.MdiParent = this;
        ProvaPackOpening.Show();
        ProvaPackOpening.CreatePictureBox();
    }
```

And that's the code of the array creation

```
    public void CreatePictureBox()
    {
        Int16 i = 0;
        PictureBox[] PicBoxArray = new PictureBox[10];

        while (i < PicBoxArray.Count())
        {
            PicBoxArray[i].BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Center;
            PicBoxArray[i].Location = new Point(0, 0);
            PicBoxArray[i].Size = new Size(128, 185);
            PicBoxArray[i].BackColor = Color.Aqua;
            PicBoxArray[i].Parent = this.panBox;
            PicBoxArray[i].Visible = true;
            panBox.Controls.Add(PicBoxArray[i]);
            PicBoxArray[i].Show();

            i++;
        }
    }
```

I've thought about manage the whole program (it would be a game) with threads, but if there's some easier solution, it will be better.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an array of objects, you're only allocating the space for the list of objects. You aren't creating the individual objects themselves. Add this line as the first line inside your `while` loop:

```
PicBoxArray[i] = new PictureBox();
```